# Speed up plotting data with many columns

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make some kind of a spaghettiplot and draw all columns from a table with 851 columns (one for the z-coordinate, the rest for a quantity as a function of height), to get something similar to this Python-powered plot:

[image: spaghetti]

To this end, my code looks roughly like below.  However, it is *very slow*.  My data also has a lot of nans.

How can I speed up the compilation of such a plot with pgfplots?  I am using pgfplots 1.12 with the lua backend.  As far as I understand, `plot gnuplot` is just for making calculations external, so would not help in this case.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\input{plot_defs}
\begin{document}
\tikzpicturedependsonfile{plot_defs.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[spv,
    name=pcprim]
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,850} {
\addplot table[y index=0, x index=\x]
    {plotdata/sPV_comparison_z_prim.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out what to do.  In the code as posted, the table is being read from disk *at every iteration of the for loop*.  To read the table once, use `\pgfplotstableread`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\input{plot_defs}
\begin{document}
\tikzpicturedependsonfile{plot_defs.tex}
\pgfplotstableread{plotdata/sPV_comparison_z_prim.dat}\tableprim
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[spv,
    name=pcprim]
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,850} {
\addplot table[y index=0, x index=\x]
    {\tableprim};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This *dramatically* speeds up the compilation.

Compilation time before: 23 minutes, 25 seconds

Compilation time after: 1 minute, 21 seconds

Comment: I'm really impressed you even let it run 23 minutes to see that it compiled.