# Multiple pgfplots from the same table indices

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a 3-column datafile where the first column specifies the paramter and the other two shall be the x and y coordinates of the respective curve. How can I make sure that curves of different parameter aren't connected and can ideally be uniquely labeled and/or colored?

I know I could use gnuplot or split up the datafile in multiple columns/files as mentioned in [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37547/pgfplots-multiple-plots-in-one-file) but I have a few hundred different parameters so I was hoping pgfplots would either allow me to filter out for each plot the coordinates that don't match their parameter or directly plot this datafile with multiple curves.

e.g.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
        1 0   0.5
        1 1   1
        1 2   1.5
        2 0   0
        2 0.5 0.5
        2 1   0.75
        2 1.5 0.865
    \end{filecontents}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot table[x index=1, y index=2]{data.dat};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Produces
[image: A single connected plot]
,but I want [image: one plot per parameter]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. I've adapted [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178632/128068) from [How to read a specific portion of a data file in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178629/how-to-read-a-specific-portion-of-a-data-file-in-pgfplots).

Use `discard if not={<-parameter-col-num->}{<-parameter-value->}`.

You mention that you have a few hundred parameters, so you could use a `foreach` loop such as:

```
\foreach \N in {1,2}{
\addplot table[x index=1, y index=2,discard if not={0}{\N}]{data.dat};
}
```

See the bottom of this post for a larger example using 5 parameters.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat} % data format: | Parameter | X | Y |
        1 0   0.5
        1 1   1
        1 2   1.5
        2 0   0
        2 0.5 0.5
        2 1   0.75
        2 1.5 0.865
\end{filecontents}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178632/128068
% Changed \thisrow{#1} to \thisrowno{#1}        
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrowno{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot table[x index=1, y index=2,discard if not={0}{1}]{data.dat};
        \addplot table[x index=1, y index=2,discard if not={0}{2}]{data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is an example of `foreach` with a larger data file of 5 parameters:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat} % data format: | Parameter | X | Y |
        1 0   0.5
        1 1   1
        1 2   1.5
        2 0   0
        2 0.5 0.5
        2 1   0.75
        2 1.5  0.865
        3 0   1.5
        3 1   2.6
        3 2   1.9
        4 0   4
        4 0.5 3.7
        4 1    3.6
        5 1.5 4.865
        5 2 2.5
\end{filecontents}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178632/128068
% Changed \thisrow{#1} to \thisrowno{#1}       
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrowno{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
        \foreach \N in {1,...,5}{
        \addplot table[x index=1, y index=2,discard if not={0}{\N}]{data.dat};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's essentially what I was looking for, however too slow and memory consuming, going OOM (! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]) at around 50 curves. Also, curiously, starting from the 5th curve, even if I only plot 5, not all datapoints will be plottet resulting in gaps within a curve. I'll try to color the curves using meta/mesh plot.

Comment: Does all your data plot quickly (albeit as one giant data set) when you don't use the code from this answer?

Comment: As one giant dataset a minimal pdflatex run is 1.14s , for {1,...,8}, it's 3.88s, for {1,...,16} 10.96s – For reference, a minimal plot like above is 0.43s

Comment: Maybe this is the solution - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236398/speed-up-plotting-data-with-many-columns

Comment: "the table is being read from disk at every iteration of the for loop. To read the table once, use \pgfplotstableread"

Comment: With this, {1,...,16} takes stunning 152.73s, I get multiple _Warning: You have an axis with empty range_ and my plot is empty

Comment: Hmm, how strange. I don't know then. Maybe ask another question with a larger MWE demonstrating the problem. I will be away from my computer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82481/discussion-between-pelipap-and-milo).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the perfect solution because it requires a change to the datafiles and misuses colormaps for curve colors.
`unbounded coords=jump` as axis parameter will interrupt the plot when `nan` `inf` or `-inf` appears in the datafile (sec. 4.4.10 of the pgfplots manual)

So the curves can be separated using a line of `NaN`s whenever the parameter changes.

```
    1 2   1.5
    NaN NaN NaN
    2 0   0
```

[image: yay, the two curves aren't connected anymore]

The parameter can be color-coded using meta and colormaps

```
\addplot[mesh, point meta = \thisrowno{0}] table[x index=1, y index=2]{data.dat};
```

It is now a mesh plot, for colored points – instead or in addition – a scatter plot can be used.

[image: they're colored]

The colormap will stretch over the range of parameters which can make single curves hard to differentiate. `point meta = {mod(\thisrowno0,8)}` will alternate the colors every 8 paramters.

Put together:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    1 0   0.5
    1 1   1
    1 2   1.5
    NaN NaN NaN
    2 0   0
    2 0.5 0.5
    2 1   0.75
    2 1.5 0.865
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
        \addplot[mesh, scatter, point meta = {mod(\thisrowno0,8)}] table[x index=1, y index=2]{data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wondering if it would be possible to use the palette instead of (or as) a colormap for consistency.

Comment: Could you also here repeat your computation times for 128 parameters with and without using `\pgfplotstableread`, please.

Comment: A palette (assuming you mean `colorbar as palette`) is also a `colormap`, but only allows certain values. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Setting any palette will work, just the default colors for plots and colormaps differ.

Answer (score 0):

### Not modifying the data file

This is more or less an advanced answer of [Milo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448407/95441), which is adapted to make all the computations in Lua -- when compiling with LuaLaTeX -- instead of in TeX together with the also [already mentioned tip](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46505571#46505571) to read the whole table only once using `\pgfplotstableread` (from the `pgplotstable` package) instead of for each `\addplot` command. I have not tested if this really improves compilation speed, but would guess so.

### Modifying the data file

In general I would recommend to restructure the data file. If all parameter modifications where calculated with the same amount of data points then you can have them all in one data file. Further depending if the computations were done at the same x coordinates you can have one x column and then all the y columns or pairwise. (Again, this only works if **all** columns have the same amount of rows. If they don't, you could fill the rest with `NaN`s.)

Or you can store each parameter variation in its own data file (of course.)

With that also "maintenance" is much easier, especially if you do not want to plot all the "hundreds of variations" in one plot -- which most likely also is not a good idea.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    % (borrowed modified data file from Milo's answer
    %  <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448407/95441>)
    \begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
        % data format: | Parameter | X | Y |
        1 0   0.5
        1 1   1
        1 2   1.5
        2 0   0
        2 0.5 0.5
        2 1   0.75
        2 1.5  0.865
        3 0   1.5
        3 1   2.6
        3 2   1.9
        4 0   4
        4 0.5 3.7
        4 1    3.6
        5 1.5 4.865
        5 2 2.5
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to make use of Lua for computations
    % when using LuaLaTeX
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % because we know we want to filter data points
        % we don't need a warning for every filtered data point in the log
        filter discard warning=false,
    ]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
            \addplot table [
                x expr={
                    ifthenelse(
                        \thisrowno{0} == \i,
                        \thisrowno{1},
                        NaN
                    )
                },
                y index=2,
            ] {\loadedtable};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: The numbers and x positions of datapoints greatly differ for different parameters (from a few dozens down to only two)

Comment: Would you be so kind to repeat the calculations you did for Milo's answer and post the results here. So we can get an impression on the computation speeds from the same machine. (Please also do the "old" calculations again to confirm that they have not drastically changed.)

Comment: And do you really plot hundreds of parameters in one plot? And in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448535/95441) you would get the same colors every 8 parameters. (Using `/colormap/Paired` from the `colorbrewer` library would at least extend this to 12.) How can you distinguish which color belongs to which parameter without any other hints/information?

Comment: I'll be looking into the runtimes of lualatex/lualatex+pgfplotstableread. I am indeed currently plotting 1024 curves using my solution below but most of them consist of only two points. My plots are similar to (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GolombCodeRedundancy.svg). I could easily update my generator to produce a single curve for all large parameters but my solution below works fine and a gnuplot solution was somewhat ok performance wise (I've developed an aversion against gnuplot). I did not yet look into using a palette instead of or as a colormap as b/w print is top priority

Comment: I'm not yet sure if I replace the color version I have created using gnuplot. There, I have used colored labels for some curves but the parameter is kind of clear because they're successively increasing so the color is primarily to depict the boundaries of single curves and the association of a label to a specific curve.

Comment: lualatex+mesh:3.30s; 
lualatex+ifnot 1,...,16:5.76s; 
lualatex+ifnot 1,...,16+pgfplotstableread:86.50s:Empty Plot; 
lualatex+ifnot 1,...,128:45.23s;

Comment: So it is much faster and less memory consuming than using pdflatex but the artifacts for paramters >5 persist – and that's not an issue with my dataset, I double-checked. If you're interested, I can send you (nopaste?) the data. I think I read about some kind of mem management issue with pgfplots datasets forced to ram before – in the documentation, I believe

Comment: lualatex+ifnot 1,...,128+pgfplotstableread:834.77s:Empty Plot  ;)

Comment: ok, so the solution *without* using `\pgfplotstableread` is faster and also shows a plot in the end. Interesting ...